# How to display the text from XMLTYPE Column including the spaces using oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have XML Data type column with the below data in it, and i want to extract the data from below XML including the spaces between the tags. after  there is one space like that after math_expression also there is one space.
when i used Extract function to extract the data from the below XML it is eliminating the spaces.

Example XMLTYPE Data column:

```
<quantity_a> <math_expression> <math display="inline" overflow="scroll"> <mrow> <mn>3</mn> <mi>x</mi> <mo>+</mo> <mn>2</mn> 
</mrow> </math> </math_expression> </quantity_a>
```

Output i Want is:
"    3 X + 2    "

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

[String-join](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_string-join.html) - description
`/quantity_a/math_expression/math/mrow/*` - it returs all elements from mrow node.

```
select xmlquery('string-join( /quantity_a/math_expression/math/mrow/*/text()," ")' passing xmltype('<quantity_a> 
<math_expression> 
<math display="inline" overflow="scroll"> 
<mrow> <mn>3</mn> <mi>x</mi> <mo>+</mo> <mn>2</mn> 
</mrow> </math> </math_expression> </quantity_a>') returning content )  from dual;
```

Comment: No, it is not returning the spaces after mrow and before mn, I am trying to print the space also.